# QMake: Referencing a library using relative paths

Tags: windows, qt-creator, qmake

I have a Qt project using SQLite, so I have the following directory structure:

```
C:\Workspace\MyProject\MyProject.pro
C:\Workspace\MyProject\sqlite3\sqlite3.lib
```

Adding sqlite3.lib with absolute paths works fine:

```
LIBS += -L"c:/Workspace/MyProject/sqlite3" -lsqlite3
```

But I can't make it work with relative paths. I try with:

```
LIBS += -L"sqlite3" -lsqlite3
```

But that fails with:

```
:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'sqlite3\sqlite3.lib'
```

I tried but `LIBS += -L"../sqlite3"` or even `LIBS += -L"../../sqlite3"`, but that didn't work either.

I'm using MSVC 2008 for the compiler toolchain.

Comment: Since it's possible to build from different directory, relative path pointing to project directory should be `$$PWD/...` (`PWD` is absolute path to directory with currently processed `.pro` file). But that doesn't explain why the custom relative library path is not searched.

Comment: Well, that looks like a legitimate answer, can you post it as such?

Comment: Done, though I really wonder how relative paths are handled by compiler/linker.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it's possible to build from different directory than project directory, relative path pointing to project directory should be prefixed with `$$PWD/` (`PWD` qmake variable contains absolute path to directory with currently processed `*.pro` file).

Your line would look like:

```
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/sqlite3" -lsqlite3
```