# Qt Creator can't find library file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have added a lib like this in my .pro file:

```
unix {
    LIBS += ../lib_dir/myLib.a

    //other includes not related to this
}
```

And when I try to build I get "undefined reference" errors for every function used from this lib and an error:

```
File not found: ../lib_dir/myLib.a(myLib.o)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

Here is what I have written:

```
LIBS += -L../lib_dir -lmyLib
```

Here is the file path:

```
/home/livanov/Project/lib_dir/myLib.a
```

Here is the path of my project that uses the lib:

```
/home/livanov/Project/client_app
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [QMake: Referencing a library using relative paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482248/qmake-referencing-a-library-using-relative-paths)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the form described in [qmake's variable reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs):

```
unix {
    LIBS += -L../lib_dir -lmyLib
}
```

If the path to your library contains spaces, use quotes:

```
unix {
    LIBS += "-L../lib dir" -lmyLib
}
```

If that doesn't work, we'll need to see the actual path to your library.

Comment: Now I just get a "cannot find lmyLib" error, the path is correct I'm 100% sure

Comment: If the path was correct, you wouldn't be here. :p That's also why I removed part of the title of your question. You can generally assume that it's a problem in your own code, not Qt's. You need to show us the full path.

Comment: Here is what I have written: LIBS += -L../lib_dir -lmyLib
Here is the file path: 
/home/livanov/Project/lib_dir/myLib.a

Here is the path of my project that uses the lib:

/home/livanov/Project/client_app

Comment: Please put that information in your question; it's where it belongs.